# Access json data from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, http-post

I have a problem accessing JSON data. I'm new to JSON and jquery so there is probably a easy solution to it and I would be glad to find out.

My jQuery:

```
  $.post(
    "currentPage.php",
    { 
    'currentPage': 1
    },
    function(data){
      $("body").append(data);  
    }
  );
```

currentPage.php:

```
$returnArray['left'] = 'test_left';
$returnArray['right'] = 'test_right';

$returnArray['numLeft'][] = 1;
$returnArray['numRight'][] = 2;
$returnArray['numRight'][] = 3;

print json_encode($returnArray);
```

I tried to access the data like this:

```
data.left
data['left']
```

but it returns blank, how is the best way to access the data in the HTML-file?

Comment: where do You wan't to access this data? on php or js side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I don't think the `post` method assumes a data return-type of json. You could set that by changing the ajax function to:

```
  $.post(
    "currentPage.php",
    { 
    'currentPage': 1
    },
    function(data){
      $("body").append(data);  
    },
    "json"
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

In JQuery, you need to set the return data type (`dataType`) to `json` so the function knows what type of data to expect and process. From the manual:

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON
>   and returns a JavaScript object. In
>   jQuery 1.4 the JSON data is parsed in
>   a strict manner; any malformed JSON is
>   rejected and a parse error is thrown.
>   (See json.org for more information on
>   proper JSON formatting.)

You can do this with the full [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call, or you can use [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/). There is no HTTP POST shortcut to return JSON (i.e. $.postJSON doesn't exist), but you can supply the `dataType` parameter to `$.ajax()` or just add the parameter to `$.post()` . When you have a `JSON` object, use `json.keyName` to access the data.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "currentPage.php",
    data: { 
        'currentPage': 1
    },
    dataType: "json",
    type: "post",
    success: function(data) {
        $("body").append(data);  
    }
});
```

Comment: It is not quite true that there exists no shortcut, you can provide the datatype as parameter to `post()`

Answer (score 1):

Provide the datatype you expect to get as parameter to the `.post()` method (in your case `json`):

```
$.post("currentPage.php",{'currentPage': 1},
  function(data){
    $("body").append(data);  
  },
  'json'     // <-- add the expected datatype
);
```

I think the default is to treat the result as HTML. Read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

> **jQuery.post( url, [ data ], [ success(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) ], [ dataType ] )**
>
> **urlA** string containing the URL to which the request is sent.
>
> **dataA** map or string that is sent to the server with the request.
>
> **success(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)** A callback function that is executed if the request succeeds.
>
> **dataType** The type of data expected from the server.