# How to select data from json

Tags: json

```
 "response": {
    "status": 1,
    "httpStatus": 200,
    "data": [
      {
        "offer_id": "8058",
        "countries": {
          "**UK**": {
            "id": "826",
            "code": "UK",
            "name": "**United Kingdom**",
            "regions": []
          }
        }
```

---

I want to

-First select **UK** from thus statement

```
"offer_id": "8058",
        "countries": {
          "UK": {
```

-Secondly i want to select name **United kingdom** from this statement

```
UK": {
            "id": "826",
            "code": "UK",
            "name": "United Kingdom",
```

From the above json data

Comment: Using what programming language?  What have you tried?

Comment: JSON itself doesn't provide a way to access the data. You usually use a programming language to convert the JSON into a data structue of that language and then access that data structure.

Comment: I tried nothing at all because iam new

Comment: Also, looks like your JSON is invalid. You may want to test in some validator such as this: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Cam correct it and then help me

Comment: You could have searched at least: [`[php] access JSON`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+access+JSON).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access json data from php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622324/access-json-data-from-php)

Comment: No..... It don't match......

Answer (score 1):

Okay if you are able to get your response in a php variable like this:

```
$response = '{ "status": 1, "httpStatus": 200, "data": [ { "offer_id": "8058", "countries": { "UK": { "id": "826", "code": "UK", "name": "United Kingdom", "regions": [] } }';
```

Then you can use json_decode():

```
$response_as_array = json_decode($response, true);
```

Do a `print_r($response_as_array)` and you can see the array structure. Hope you can get the required values from that array.

For example `$response_as_array['data'][0]['countries']['UK']['name']` will give you `United Kingdom`.