# Getting PHP variables inside of foreach loop from JSON

Tags: php, json, variables, foreach

Please review the following code I am using:

```
<?php

$head = '[ { "status": "active", "confirmed_opt_in": null, "account_id": 1738888, "fields": { "first_name": "Ash", "last_name": "Wright" }, "member_id": 262268888, "last_modified_at": "@D:2016-12-30T19:58:25", "member_status_id": "a", "plaintext_preferred": false, "email_error": null, "member_since": "@D:2014-05-05T16:01:21", "bounce_count": 0, "deleted_at": null, "email": "ashwright@gmail.com" } ]';

$data = json_decode($head,true); // the second param will cast it as array, default is obejct. See the linked docs of json_decode!
foreach($data as $item) {
    $id=$item['member_id'];
    $email=$item['email'];
    echo "ID: $id EMAIL: $email<br/>";
    // put your code here to write into DB or whatever you wanna do!
}

?>
```

In addition to the `$id` and `$email` variables I would also like to capture the first name and last name from the above JSON return in order to have variables for the first name and last name. Could someone please so me the syntax to accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access json data from php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622324/access-json-data-from-php)

Answer (score 1):

You should `print_r` your json decoded array. The first and last names are within the "fields" key.

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
```

**Array:**

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [status] => active
        [confirmed_opt_in] => 
        [account_id] => 1738888
        [fields] => Array
            (
                [first_name] => Ash
                [last_name] => Wright
            )

        [member_id] => 262268888
        [last_modified_at] => @D:2016-12-30T19:58:25
        [member_status_id] => a
        [plaintext_preferred] => 
        [email_error] => 
        [member_since] => @D:2014-05-05T16:01:21
        [bounce_count] => 0
        [deleted_at] => 
        [email] => ashwright@gmail.com
    )

 )
```

**Solution:**

```
$first_name = $item['fields']['first_name'];
$last_name = $item['fields']['last_name'];

echo "Name : ". $first_name . ' '.$last_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should try two thinging, here is muliple array
1) decode json

```
Array
```

(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [status] => active
            [confirmed_opt_in] => 
            [account_id] => 1738888
            [fields] => Array
                (
                    [first_name] => Ash
                    [last_name] => Wright
                )

```
        [member_id] => 262268888
        [last_modified_at] => @D:2016-12-30T19:58:25
        [member_status_id] => a
        [plaintext_preferred] => 
        [email_error] => 
        [member_since] => @D:2014-05-05T16:01:21
        [bounce_count] => 0
        [deleted_at] => 
        [email] => ashwright@gmail.com
    )
```

)

> Use for loop or foreach loop for getting mulitple array values

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
   $first_name = $value['fields']['first_name'];
   $last_name = $value['fields']['last_name'];  
}
```

> you should print first_name and last_name

```
echo "Name : ".$first_name." ".$last_name;
```

2) Use extract() in foreach loop

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    extract($value);
    $first_name = $fields['first_name'];
    $last_name = $fields['last_name'];
}
```

> print first_name and last_name

```
echo "Name : ".$first_name." ".$last_name;
```

> If you need to print directly first_name and last_name then you should try this one.

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    extract($value);
    extract($fields);
    echo "Name : ".$first_name." ".$last_name;  
}
```